# spring-boot-jms Redeliverypolicy bean ignored?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, spring-jms

So I'm setting up Spring JMS with ActiveMQ, and I'm testing my setup a bit.

I'm trying to setup a `RedeliveryPolicy` so it isn't instantly retried, but I noticed in my logging + ActiveMQ broker that it's instantly retried and not using my `RedeliveryPolicy` bean. Could anyone point me out what I'm doing wrong? According to what I could find in the docs it seems to be correct. (and if anyone sees why my `individualdeadletterstrategy` is ignored but put on the general DLQ always welcome).

```java
    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public DeadLetterStrategy deadLetterStrategy() {
        IndividualDeadLetterStrategy deadLetterStrategy = new IndividualDeadLetterStrategy();
        deadLetterStrategy.setQueueSuffix(".dlq");
        deadLetterStrategy.setUseQueueForQueueMessages(true);
        return deadLetterStrategy;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy() {
        RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
        redeliveryPolicy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(5000);
        redeliveryPolicy.setBackOffMultiplier(2);
        redeliveryPolicy.setUseExponentialBackOff(true);
        redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(5);
        return redeliveryPolicy;
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue myQueue() {
        return new ActiveMQQueue("myQueue");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deadLetterStrategy` concerns broker, so you have to define beans as below

take a look at 
http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.region.policy.DeadLetterStrategy;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.region.policy.IndividualDeadLetterStrategy;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.region.policy.PolicyEntry;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.region.policy.PolicyMap;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, classes = { Configuration.class,
        Component.class }))
public class ActiveMQConfigurationDeadLetterStrategy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext app = SpringApplication.run(ActiveMQConfigurationDeadLetterStrategy.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
        final BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
        broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
        broker.addConnector("vm://localhost");
        broker.setPersistent(false);
        broker.setDestinationPolicy(policyMap());
        return broker;
    }

    @Bean
    public PolicyMap policyMap() {
        PolicyMap destinationPolicy = new PolicyMap();
        List<PolicyEntry> entries = new ArrayList<PolicyEntry>();
        PolicyEntry queueEntry = new PolicyEntry();
        queueEntry.setQueue(">");
        queueEntry.setDeadLetterStrategy(deadLetterStrategy());
        PolicyEntry topicEntry = new PolicyEntry();
        topicEntry.setTopic(">");
        topicEntry.setDeadLetterStrategy(deadLetterStrategy());
        entries.add(queueEntry);
        entries.add(topicEntry);
        destinationPolicy.setPolicyEntries(entries);
        return destinationPolicy;
    }

    @Bean
    public DeadLetterStrategy deadLetterStrategy() {
        IndividualDeadLetterStrategy deadLetterStrategy = new IndividualDeadLetterStrategy();
        deadLetterStrategy.setQueueSuffix(".dlq");
        deadLetterStrategy.setUseQueueForQueueMessages(true);
        return deadLetterStrategy;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy() {
        RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
        redeliveryPolicy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(5000);
        redeliveryPolicy.setBackOffMultiplier(2);
        redeliveryPolicy.setUseExponentialBackOff(true);
        redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(5);
        return redeliveryPolicy;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy());
        return connectionFactory;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you use an external AMQ the deadLetterStrategy can only be set in the destination policy map of the activemq.xml configuration file
For example :

```
<broker>

  <destinationPolicy>
    <policyMap>
      <policyEntries>
        <!-- Set the following policy on all queues using the '>' wildcard -->
        <policyEntry queue=">">
          <deadLetterStrategy>
            <!--
              Use the prefix 'DLQ.' for the destination name, and make
              the DLQ a queue rather than a topic
            -->
            <individualDeadLetterStrategy queuePrefix="DLQ." useQueueForQueueMessages="true"/>
          </deadLetterStrategy>
        </policyEntry>
      </policyEntries>
    </policyMap>
  </destinationPolicy>

</broker>






import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.region.policy.DeadLetterStrategy;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.region.policy.IndividualDeadLetterStrategy;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.region.policy.PolicyEntry;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.region.policy.PolicyMap;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, classes = { Configuration.class,
        Component.class }))
public class ActiveMQConfigurationDeadLetterStrategy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext app = SpringApplication.run(ActiveMQConfigurationDeadLetterStrategy.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy() {
        RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
        redeliveryPolicy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(5000);
        redeliveryPolicy.setBackOffMultiplier(2);
        redeliveryPolicy.setUseExponentialBackOff(true);
        redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(5);
        return redeliveryPolicy;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
        connectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy());
        return connectionFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, if I try this it starts up a new embedded activemq rather than the one I am pointing to. (swapped the first addConnector with my url, and removed the second addConnector.

Comment: @KristofPlennings Okk i do not understood that you are pointing to an external AMQ! So in this case the deadLetterStrategy can only be set in the destination policy map of the activemq.xml configuration file, see my updated answer